# Appium: Android Resource ID: translates to what in their selenium integration?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

So for example I have:

```
wd.findElement.By(name("searchBttn"));
```

the resource-id in the ui xml screen cap is 
`com.aut.android:id/searchBttn`

and Appium can't find the item. I have tried with ID and Name. Is there something else here i could try is there a direct line for line correlation list somewhere that i am missing?

Comment: I could not find much documentation on this topic. You can refer this link - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/LcjbXPFX1N0

Answer (score 7):

You can find an Android item in Appium by Resource ID, but you have to specify the entire package name along with the resource id:

```
wd.findElement.By(id("com.aut.android:id/searchBttn"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch element by few more way other than name or id is not available

Can find element find by using resource-id like below example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='login']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cash']")).click();
```

Here: `com.android.calculator2:id/digit5` is complete resource id and can use like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.calculator2:id/digit5")).click();
```

Can find by class name:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.Button")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

At least name works for me. I'm trying to find out how it works for ID, but you can look at the following.

Example: If the button text is set to "testbtn", then you can access it from Appium with the following command:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("testbtn")).click();
```

This works for me, try it.

EDIT:
As one of the Appium devs stated [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/appium-discuss/LcjbXPFX1N0/gpNnVpM4Yi4J), it currently seems to be not possible to access elements by ID on Android.

EDIT2:
This feature is now implemented! As I found out, you can now access elements from Android by ID using selendroid (it seems to be a sub part of Appium).

In your test class you need to specify `capabilities.setCapability("device", "selendroid");` when setting up instead of `capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");`

Now you can just access a button with

```
driver.findElement(By.id("testbtn")).click();
```

You can find the official documentation from Selendroid [here](http://selendroid.io/native.html)

Comment: I am trying to run appium tests through Selendroid to be able to access UI elements using ids. But I am getting "Device selendroid not configured yet" when I start the test. Can you please let me know how we can go about that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in python where I couldn't find the elements that had the id attribute even though I could see them in the appium inspector.
Some of the apps have multiple contexts that the driver can handle like NATIVE_APP & WEB_VIEW so I had to switch the context of the driver to WEB_VIEW so it could find the elements with the driver.find_elements_by_id("")(**python syntax**)

Documentation on how to switch contexts with code examples - 
http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/index.html