# Unable to click/select the button and text field

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YDjm.jpg)Friends,

Below is my code, the app launches when run, but its unable to select the button, gives an error as below:

Is it because i am using RemoteWebDriver instead of AndroidDriver?

Appium error log:

```
 > info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":7,"value":{"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.","origValue":"Element was not found."},"sessionId":"633dd3fe-7233-eb66-8903-c63b69246cf0"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/633dd3fe-7233-eb66-8903-c63b69246cf0/element 500 30181.879 ms - 201
```

> info: --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/633dd3fe-7233-eb66-8903-c63b69246cf0 {}
>   info: Shutting down appium session

Eclipse error log:

```
Test Started
FAILED: test
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located   on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not   provide any stacktrace information)
 Command duration or timeout: 30.19 seconds
 For documentation on this error, please visit:     http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
  Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:20'
  System info: host: 'NCA1026471', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7',   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
 Capabilities [{app=C:\Appium\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk,     appPackage=io.selendroid.testapp, rotatable=true, networkConnectionEnabled=true,    warnings={}, handlesAlerts=true, deviceName=Lokesh Gangaiah, version=0.17.0,   platform=ANDROID, appActivity=io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity, desired=  {app=C:\Appium\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk, appPackage=io.selendroid.testapp,  appActivity=io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity, platformVersion=5.0,  browserName=, platformName=Android, deviceName=Lokesh Gangaiah, device=Android}, acceptSslCerts=true, platformVersion=21, automationName=selendroid,   browserName=selendroid, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,  platformName=android, device=Android}]
Session ID: 633dd3fe-7233-eb66-8903-c63b69246cf0
 *** Element info: {Using=id,   value=io.selendroid.testapp:id/buttonStartWebview}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

java code:

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
 import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.mobile.*;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;  
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
 import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
 import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 public class testP1 {

 public static RemoteWebDriver driver;
//public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

        File appDir = new File ("C:\\Appium\\");
        //File app = new File (appDir,"CarsGuide com   au_v1.0.8.1_apkpure.com.apk");
        File app = new File (appDir,"selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
        //capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Lokesh Gangaiah");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");

        capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "io.selendroid.testapp");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity");

        //capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "au.com.carsguide");
        //capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "au.com.carsguide.activity.HomeActivity");

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Test Started");

    WebElement ButtonElement =     driver.findElementById("io.selendroid.testapp:id/buttonStartWebview");
    ButtonElement.click();

    Thread.sleep(3000L);

    System.out.println("Test has been completed");

    //System.out.println("Hello2");


    //       driver.findElementByName("Search Cars for Sale").click();
    //By.id("au.com.carsguide:id/search_btn").findElement(driver).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000L);

   }

  @AfterClass
     public void tearDown()
     {
        driver.quit();
    }

 }
```

New error after adding wait : log from the eclipse console

```
 Test Started
 FAILED: test
 org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id:    io.selendroid.testapp:id/buttonStartWebview
```

Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:20'
System info: host: 'NCA1026471', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7',   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    Capabilities [{app=C:\Appium\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk,      appPackage=io.selendroid.testapp, rotatable=true, networkConnectionEnabled=true,   warnings={}, handlesAlerts=true, deviceName=Lokesh Gangaiah, version=0.17.0,   platform=ANDROID, appActivity=io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity, desired={app=C:\Appium\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk, appPackage=io.selendroid.testapp,    appActivity=io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity, platformVersion=5.0, browserName=, platformName=Android, deviceName=Lokesh Gangaiah, device=Android},    acceptSslCerts=true, platformVersion=21, automationName=selendroid, browserName=selendroid, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,   platformName=android, device=Android}]
     Session ID: 990a6104-0d06-f75a-876c-531a23388b7c

### Tried With AndroidDriver get below err:

```
 FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUpBeforeClass
 java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods   FindsByAccessibilityId<WebElement>.findElementsByAccessibilityId(String),   AppiumDriver<RequiredElementType>.findElementsByAccessibilityId(String)
The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods   FindsByCssSelector.findElementsByCssSelector(String),   AppiumDriver<RequiredElementType>.findElementsByCssSelector(String)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct id which is available on the page?

Comment: Yes the id is correct, i cross verifyed

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your locators page

Comment: yes just now uploaded

Comment: Wait you want to tap on EN button right?

Comment: @Gaurav Either of them ,either button or text field,..non of them is working

Comment: did you try your own suggested fix: `Is it because i am using RemoteWebDriver instead of AndroidDriver?` Change `public static RemoteWebDriver driver;` to `public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;` and `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);` to  `driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`

Comment: @Lokesh seems like you have selected the wrong locator in the screenshot. You have select google button which is selected by red color. Can you please tap on EN button and update the screenshot accordingly

Comment: @Gaurav, the below suggesed code by you worked fine, it also worked fine for EN button..which has the content-desc "buttonTestCD",so my script clicked the button as well...Thanks a lot.

Comment: But I have two more questions: 1. I am actually trying to automate for another app and i observed that the other app does not have any Content-desc,what should i be using in this case? 2. What is the difference b/w AndroidDriver and RemoteDriver, which one should i be using, it working fine on RemoteDriver now, but  just curious to know

Comment: @econoMichael, Thanks for the reply, did try out with AndroidDriver, but i am getting the below error:

Comment: @Lokesh I am glad it worked for you. please post a separate question with all those queries. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some wait command before clicking:

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Test Started");

    //wait for the button to show up before clicking
    waitForElementPresent();
    WebElement ButtonElement =     driver.findElementByName("buttonStartWebviewCD");
    ButtonElement.click();
}
     public void waitForElementPresent() {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("buttonStartWebviewCD")));
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, did try with the above, below error is seen:

Comment: @Lokesh can you please share the screenshot of your UIAutomator. That way i can help you. Seems like you are using the wrong locator

Comment: Sure will try that and let u know

Comment: the above code works , but have few questions, will be great if u could helpmeout

Comment: I did get some clarification, i was using resource-id with complete package, after seeing this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362400/appium-android-resource-id-translates-to-what-in-their-selenium-integration/35905822#35905822  It helped me change the resource id to be used only to the button_name..then it worked

Comment: ex: using this worked driver.findElement(By.id("search_btn")).click();; rather than using completed "au.com.carsguide:id/search_btn"